# I am having some difficulties on my wrong multiple where query

Tags: php, sql

When I just let one WHERE and remove the other it returns me the correct result. When I have it as is it does not display anything. How can I write correctly my logic below?

My aim is to display only the result who satisfy the "extra1 = $value1 and extra2 = $value2 and extra3 = $value3."

I read somewhere that I have to add the *addslashes*. What is the use of it?

```
$value1 = addslashes($_GET['extra1']);
$value2 = addslashes($_GET['extra2']);
$value3 = addslashes($_GET['extra3']);

$theposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE ID IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT post_id
   FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
   WHERE meta_key = 'extra1' AND meta_value = '$value1'
   WHERE meta_key = 'extra2' AND meta_value = '$value2'
   WHERE meta_key = 'extra3' AND meta_value = '$value3'

)");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database supports intersections then you can do this:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
WHERE meta_key = 'extra1' AND meta_value = '$value1' 
    INTERSECT
SELECT post_id
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
WHERE meta_key = 'extra2' AND meta_value = '$value2'
    INTERSECT
SELECT post_id
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
WHERE meta_key = 'extra3' AND meta_value = '$value3'
```

That will give you all the `post_id`s that have extra1/value1, extra2/value2, and extra3/value3.

If you don't have `INTERSECT` (such as, AFAIK, MySQL), you can try `HAVING`:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM {$wpdb->postmeta}
WHERE meta_key = 'extra1' AND meta_value = '$value1'
   OR meta_key = 'extra2' AND meta_value = '$value2'
   OR meta_key = 'extra3' AND meta_value = '$value3'
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: To clear my mind... It will show a post that has metakey as extra1 and metavalue as value1 even if the post does not have metakey as extra2 and metavalue as value2? Because I want only the post that satisfy all the WHERE. The post must have extra1/value1, extra2/value2, and extra3/value3 to be displayed.

Comment: @Mairy: Both options (I added an update after your comment) will produce `post_id`s that satisfy all three conditions at the same time. `INTERSECT` is just the usual intersection from set theory. The HAVING approach is a bit harder on the brain but it is, more or less, a way of using an aggregate (`COUNT` in this case) to select results as you can't do that in `WHERE`; this approach assumes that you don't have any duplicate (post_id,meta_key,meta_value) triples in your table though.

Comment: @Mairy: BTW, there's no need for `DISTINCT` when you're using `IN`. `IN` is a set operation so it won't care about duplicates. `DISTINCT` does have a non-trivial execution cost as it usually involves sorting the results and doing a table scan of the sorted results.

Comment: I have accepted your answer even if I can't display any results. I have replaced my query with yours between the `WHERE ID IN
(` and `)");` Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Only one WHERE is possible per (sub) query. Replace subsequent WHEREs with ANDs. By the way: what is the error message saying?

Comment: How can I do this? My aim is to display only the result who satisfy the "extra1 = value1 and extra2 = value2 and extra3 = value3."

Answer (score 0):

Combine them with the OR keyword

```
 WHERE meta_key = 'extra1' AND meta_value = '$value1' 
 OR 
 meta_key = 'extra2' AND meta_value = '$value2' 
 OR
 meta_key = 'extra3' AND meta_value = '$value3'
```

Comment: Can you please post the structure of your tables, and exactly what you expect from it. Perhaps some sample values would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
SELECT p.post_title FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS p
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm
    WHERE pm.meta_key = 'extra1' AND pm.meta_value = '$value1' 
      AND pm.post_id = p.ID
  )
  AND EXISTS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm
    WHERE pm.meta_key = 'extra2' AND pm.meta_value = '$value2'
      AND pm.post_id = p.ID
  )
  AND EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} AS pm
    WHERE pm.meta_key = 'extra3' AND pm.meta_value = '$value3'
      AND pm.post_id = p.ID
  )
```